# Complex Non-liner First order ODE problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-optimization

Good day people

I am modelling a "water bottle rocket" using basic Continuum Mechanics.
I have found a equation describing the acceleration of the rocket.  I need to integrate this function to find the velocity of the rocket at a point in time and then integrate it once more to find the distance it will have travelled by a certain time.

the equation :
$$\frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{1082.8}{vt} - 0.917\frac vt + \frac{11942.5}{0.231vt+0.013v^2t^2} + 4.9$$
Where $v(0) = 0$ and $791-3.6vt \geq 0$.

I have tried to solve this using Matlab, Wolfram Alpha and praying.  But non have produced an answer that I can integrate again.

Thank you for the help

Comment: Are you sure there is a $v/t$ term ?

Comment: You tried prayer? You thought "this is a logical subject, you know what will help?" and decided to pray for the answer?

Comment: I don't think you will be able to get a closed solution for $v$ here. Numerical methods are probably the way to go...

Comment: @AlecTeal, it's possible it's a joke.

Comment: I think dimensionally speaking the terms on the right are jibberish. All terms must be dimensional consistent I.e lhs is acceleration the other terms except v/t are not unless the constants have meaning. But it's good to try solve as an ode :)

Comment: @Chinny84 : Yes, the constants have meaning and the equation is dimensionally sound.  I could type in the original question with which I started, but that would take a week.

Comment: @AlectTeal : Read Bennet Gardiner's post